# How to fix EOF error during docker push command

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-image, docker-for-windows

I try to push an image in my public docker repository, but after some minutes I have this problem:

[image]

and during pushing, the following occurs many times (when retrying):

[image]

My version of docker is the following:

[image]

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Best is to open a issue on docker github repo.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/2349 @TarunLalwani

Comment: Are you behind a proxy by any chance? If so, there are many different answers to help - including editing your proxy config.

Comment: My issue was solved with the accepted solution described on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70828205/pushing-an-image-to-ecr-getting-retrying-in-seconds

Answer (score 41):

[image: docker push to ECR error]
When I push an image to ECR, an EOF error occured.
The reason is remote repository[`jdk-8-newrelic`] does not exist.
After creating the repository, `PUSH` succeeded.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction: Terraform was creating the image repository with a different name from the one I was passing to `docker push`.

Comment: My issue was similar. I forgot to give myself permission to the repo.

Comment: make sure the repository is named correctly (especially when using a structured naming convention like -> frontend/website)

Answer (score 19):

I got this error when my image name was incorrectly formatted.
I was trying to push an image called `registry-url/my-repository/my-image-name:tag`
This is wrong; I need a repository per image name. `registry-url/my-image-name:tag` worked, once I created the repository named `my-image-name`.

This was on ECR.

Comment: Why are you so confused with your answer, "once I created the repository named my-image-name."

Comment: This answer is helpful. It is not immediately obvious that "repository" means _everything except the tag_.

Comment: if you are still unclear, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46242170/1180117) might help.

Answer (score 15):

I was missing this policy ***AmazonEc2COntainerRegistryFullAccess*** in permission of the iam user

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. The AWS ECR I was trying to push to just didn't have any permissions attached to it...

Answer (score 9):

If you have profiles under ~/.aws/credentials (linux), you might need to specify profile name

```
aws ecr get-login-password  --profile <PROFILE-NAME>  | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <ECR_NAME>.dkr.ecr.<REGION>.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer helped me figure out my problem, and that was because I have multiple AWS accounts for various environments and I was using the default one mistakenly when authenticating with ECR for docker login. Thanks.

Comment: Make you are connected to right profile with ECR access.

Answer (score 5):

In case you are trying to push into the AWS ECR, this happens when the connection to the repository has failed.  This could be either because

1. the repository doesn't exist
2. the repository exists but in a different region
3. the AWS credentials are incorrect.
4. the AWS credentials have just been corrected

Once you have the repository created in the correct region and the AWS cli Credentials are corrected, ensure that you run the AWS docker login command once again and repeat the tag and push steps.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem pushing to a private docker repository, and the problem was wrong credentials.

Try to read the logs:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source Docker -After (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5) | Sort-Object Time
```

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/troubleshooting#finding-logs

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had saved AWS credentials from another account where I did not have full access anymore. Check your C:\Users\YourUserName.aws\credentials if you are on Win.

Comment: This was my issue as well. I was mistakenly using my credentials for another environment.

Answer (score 1):

Please try creating the repository before pushing it using Docker.

```
aws ecr create-repository --repository-name lambda-update-query-object --region us-east-1 --image-scanning-configuration scanOnPush=true --image-tag-mutability MUTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met this issue nowadays when I am pushing an image to a private registry. And I checked out the Docker log and found that there was something unexpected about the proxy but I did not have to push to my private through the proxy. So I added my registry address to the Docker proxy whitelist to skip the proxy, and it worked. I wish it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, You need to create a repository in AWS ECR.**
PFB for AWS AC.

docker push aws-ac-id.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/build-agent:latest

Here I have created a build-agent ECR repository and the above command got successful.
Don't forget to run the below command.

*aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin aws-ac-id.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com*