# ECR - What is the registry and what is a repository

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

Trying to familiarize myself with ECR - i understand that you should be able to push as many repositories as you like to Docker registry.

However, ECR has a concept of a 'repository'.
So if i have 10 different containers comprising my app, does it mean i need 10 repositories in a registry?

Can i have one repository and push 10 different containers with their 'latest' tags?

Currently if i tag another image with the same {registry}/{repository_name} pattern, it replaces `latest` tag on my other image:

[image: ECR overview]

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you want to get the detailed descriptions, I would check out the [What Is Amazon EC2 Container Registry?](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/what-is-ecr.html) page, which describes the components in detail, but the high level difference between the two is this: **Each account** has a **Registry**, **each Registry** can contain **several repositories**. **Each Repository** can contain **several Images**. An image can have Several Tags, **a Tag can only exist once per Repository**.

If you look at the reference to a repository:

```
[account].dkr.ecr.[region].amazonaws.com/[repository_name]
```

The part in front of the first `/` is your registry, the part after the first `/` is your repository.

So what you're experiencing here is that by pushing a second image to the same repository, you're changing the reference that the `latest` tag is pointing to.

If you want to have multiple distinct images, each with their own `latest` tag, each one should have it's own Repository. Based on the Pricing for ECR, [you only pay based on the storage size and transfer from an ECR Repo](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/pricing/), so there's little benefit to not creating additional repos.

Comment: the issue, however, is that i need to have a different IAM principal with 'create repository' permissions if i want to push new images from CI; or pre-create all repositories. If i could push directly to a registry it would make a bit more sense. e.g. i don't see any value int he ECR repository concept.

Comment: Ah, that all sounds like useful information to have originally included in your question. That said, given that you are thinking of putting all of the images in a single repository anyway, I don't see the downside in allowing your CI to create new repositories. If I'm understanding your use case correctly, I don't know of any docker registries that would be well suited to your use case.

Comment: Automatic repository creation would solve this issue, which is highly requested but still just a proposal: https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/853  and https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/799 .