# Github action: [error]Process completed with exit code 1. Trying to push docker image into ecr repo

Tags: dockerfile, github-actions, aws-fargate, cicd, amazon-ecr

[image]

I am try to do aws pipeline using githubaction and deploy to aws fargate.  I can able to create my docker image but can't able to push to ECR repo with github action.

name: CI
on:
push:
branches: [ develop ]
pull_request:
branches: [ develop ]
jobs:
build:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
# Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
- uses: actions/checkout@v2

```
  # Runs a single command using the runners shell
  - name: Lint code
    run: echo "Linting repository!"
  # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell
  - name: Run unit tests
    run: |
      echo "Running unit tests"
  - name: Configure AWS credentials
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
    with:
      aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      aws-region: us-east-2

  - name: Login to Amazon ECR
    id: login-ecr
    uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1
  - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
    id: build-image
    env:
      ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
      ECR_REPOSITORY: cmssdemo
      IMAGE_TAG: latest
    run: |
      docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
      docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
      echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"
  - name: Download task definition
    run: |
      aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition ${{ secrets.ECS_CONTAINER_DEFINITION }} \
      --query taskDefinition > task-definition.json
  - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
    id: task-def
    uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
    with:
      task-definition: task-definition.json
      container-name: ${{ secrets.ECS_CONTAINER_NAME }}
      image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}
 - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition
    uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
    with:
      task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
      service: ${{ secrets.ECS_SERVICE }}
      cluster: ${{ secrets.ECS_CLUSTER }}
      wait-for-service-stability: true
```

My githubaction script

Answer (score 0):

You may fix it by going into ECR -> Repositories -> Permissions then adding a new policy statement with principal:* and the following actions:

```
"ecr:BatchGetImage",
"ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
"ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
"ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
"ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
"ecr:PutImage",
"ecr:UploadLayerPart"
```

Be sure to add more restrictive principals.

Ref:
[Pushing an image to ECR, getting "Retrying in ... seconds"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70828205/pushing-an-image-to-ecr-getting-retrying-in-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Go to ECR -> Permissions -> Add Statement

- Add the Iam User in the permission
- Select the necessary Actions

You should end up with a JSON like this

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "new statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:user/ECS-User"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
        "ecr:DescribeImages",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
        "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
        "ecr:PutImage",
        "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```